# Select random 3 client from JSON response and pass in to http request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have the following JSON response,

```
[
    {
        "clientId": "ClientID 1",
        "studyId": "AutomationTest",
        "applicationName": "Monitoring Package",
        "referenceId": "12345"
    },
    {
        "clientId": "ClientID 2",
        "studyId": "AutomationTest83",
        "applicationName": "BulkLoader",
        "referenceId": null
    },
    {
        "clientId": "ClientID 34",
        "studyId": "AutomationTest1",
        "applicationName": "Monitoring Package",
        "referenceId": "12345"
    },
    {
        "clientId": "ClientID 126",
        "studyId": "Automation<\/>Test1",
        "applicationName": "Monitoring Package",
        "referenceId": "12345"
    },
    {
        "clientId": "ClientID 67",
        "studyId": "Automation Test1",
        "applicationName": "Monitoring Package",
        "referenceId": "Ref 12345"
    },
    {
        "clientId": "ClientID 54",
        "studyId": "Automation Test 2",
        "applicationName": "Monitoring Package",
        "referenceId": "Ref 12345"
    },
    {
        "clientId": "ClientID 52",
        "studyId": "A StudyId",
        "applicationName": "Monitoring Package",
        "referenceId": "A ReferenceId"
    }
]
```

I want to select any random 3 client's value (ex: Value 1, Value 2 and Value 3) and pass into my next http request like

```
$filter: (clientId eq 'Value1' or clientId eq 'Value 2' or clientId eq 'Value 3')
```

I am able to select 1 value with the following script,

```
def jsonResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def selectRandomClientID = jsonResponse.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, jsonResponse.size()))
vars.put('clientID', selectRandomClientID.clientId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you need to modify the script a little,

```
for (int n = 0; n < 3;n++) {
    def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
    def randomEntry = json.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(n, json.size()))
     vars.put('clientID', randomEntry.clientId)
}
```

[image]